# How to sort number columns from csv file read in using D3.js - columns read in as strings

Tags: javascript, sorting, csv, d3.js

I read in a CSV file using D3.js.  I would like the table to now be sortable depending on the header that is clicked by a user.  The code below alphabetically sorts the data in the table perfectly, but when it comes to the cost/savings columns they get sorted as strings, like such:

```
$999
$87
$8890
$7
$5000
```

Which is obviously not correct.  So I'm wondering how I can perform mathematical sort on these columns.  Below is the bulk of my code (essentially the same as http://bl.ocks.org/AMDS/4a61497182b8fcb05906 with a small change in the sort):

```
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.csv("../reservations/arc.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

              var sortAscending = true;
              var table = d3.select('#page-wrap').append('table');
              var titles = d3.keys(data[0]);
              var headers = table.append('thead').append('tr')
                               .selectAll('th')
                               .data(titles).enter()
                               .append('th')
                               .text(function (d) {
                                        return d;
                                })
                               .on('click', function (d) {
                                       headers.attr('class', 'header');
                                       if (sortAscending) {
                                         sortAscending = false;
                                         this.className = 'aes';
                                         rows.sort(function(a, b){return d3.ascending(b[d],a[d])}); 
                                       } else {
                                             sortAscending = true;
                                             this.className = 'des';
                                             rows.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.descending(b[d], a[d])});
                                       }

                               });

              var rows = table.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
                           .data(data).enter()
                           .append('tr');
              rows.selectAll('td')
                .data(function (d) {
                    return titles.map(function (k) {
                            return { 'value': d[k], 'name': k};
                    });
                }).enter()
                .append('td')
                .attr('data-th', function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.value;
                });
      });
    </script>
```

Im guessing that these columns need to be parsed as numbers using Number() and a simple regex, but I'm not sure how I would do this. I tried NaN but every column passes that condition since they are initially read in as strings.   Or if there's another flexible sort function by all means

I'm new to javascript so bridging gaps can be a little difficult. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a sample of your dataset but I assume that you're getting your cost column with $ sign already.

In that case, I would start with slicing the value first: `StringValue.slice(1)` and get the numerical part. Then try reading it as an Integer using the `+` unary operator or `parseInt("some string")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an alternate sort function that's conditional on that column.  Say that column is named "Cost":

```
...

    .on('click', function(d) {
      headers.attr('class', 'header');

      if (sortAscending) {
        if (d === "Cost"){
          rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            var b = +b[d].substring(1),
                a = +a[d].substring(1);
            return b < a;
          });
        }else{
          rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b[d] < a[d];
          });
        }
        sortAscending = false;
        this.className = 'aes';
      } else {
        if (d === "Cost"){
          rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            var b = +b[d].substring(1),
                a = +a[d].substring(1);
            return b > a;
          });
        }else{
          rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b[d] > a[d];
          });
        }
        sortAscending = true;
        this.className = 'des';
      }
    });
```

---

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/83073o0Df0hLNJnSWUQs?p=preview).